# String Variable returns nothing

Tags: python, split

I have made a simple program:

```
Query = raw_input('Keyword: ')
QuerySplit = Query.Split()
QSL = len(QuerySplit)
l=0
string = "Search contains keyword"
for i in dem:
      for k in range (l and (QSL-1)):
           if QuerySplit[k] in i.text:
                   print string
```

Dem has several paras. Nothing particular here.
The logic of this is basically if i search for a term, the program returns a string even if one of the searched terms is present. This is not even once was string returned despite the text having 'searched term'.

Comment: `range (l and (QSL-1))` should be `range(l, QSL - 1)`?

Comment: I am not clear what is "dem" and what i.text refers to. Can you give any example of dem variable?

Comment: @minitech Interestingly there is no syntax error there, however.

Comment: @arshajii: It could make some sense somehow, but it looks like `l` doesn’t change…

Comment: @arshajii ends up as `range(QSL-1)`....

Answer (score 3):

`range (l and (QSL-1))` should be  `range(QSL)`.

`l and (QSL-1)` will actually evaluate to `0`, as `and` condition short-circuits at the first Falsy value and returns that value. If all items were `True` values then the last item is returned.

```
>>> 0 and 2
0
>>> 1 and 2
2
>>> 1 and 0 and 3
0
>>> 1 and 2 and 3
3
```

In python you can iterate over the list itself, no need of indexes:

```
for strs in QuerySplit:
    if strs in i.text:
        print string
```

`range`:

```
>>> range(4)
[0, 1, 2, 3]
>>> range(2)
[0, 1]
```

help on `range`:

```
range(stop) -> list of integers
range(start, stop[, step]) -> list of integers

Return a list containing an arithmetic progression of integers.
range(i, j) returns [i, i+1, i+2, ..., j-1]; start (!) defaults to 0.
When step is given, it specifies the increment (or decrement).
For example, range(4) returns [0, 1, 2, 3].  The end point is omitted!
These are exactly the valid indices for a list of 4 elements.
```

Answer (score 1):

I think using set intersection (of QuerySplit and i.text), and seeing if result is disjoint / not disjoint will do the job.

```
Query = raw_input('Keyword: ')
QuerySplit = Query.Split()
QuerySplitSet = set(QuerySplit)
string = "Search contains keyword"
for i in dem:
    if (not QuerySplitSet.isdisjoint(set(i.text))):
        print string
```